# How to properly copy arrays when using backtracking algorithm in Golang?

Tags: arrays, go, backtracking

I have a simple array with values [1, 2, 3], and I'd like to find all permutations. I don't understand why moving 'copying' part of the code before the loop breaks the program.

```
func generatePermutations(curr, remains []int) [][]int {
   if len(remains) == 0 {
      return [][]int{curr}
   }

   var res [][]int

   // DOESN'T WORK
   c, r := make([]int, len(curr)), make([]int, len(remains))
   copy(c, curr)
   copy(r, remains)

   for i := 0; i < len(remains); i++ {
      // WORKS
      //c, r := make([]int, len(curr)), make([]int, len(remains))
      //copy(c, curr)
      //copy(r, remains)
      
      curr = append(curr, remains[i])
      res = append(res, generatePermutations(curr, append(append(remains[:i]), remains[i+1:]...))...)

      curr = c
      remains = r
   }

   return res
}
```

When copy is outside the loop the result is the following:
[[1 2 3] [1 3 2] [2 1 3] [2 3 1] [3 3 3] [3 3 3]]

When copy is inside the loop the result is the following:
[[1 2 3] [1 3 2] [2 1 3] [2 3 1] [3 1 2] [3 2 1]]

In the first output there are two arrays with [3,3,3] which is wrong

Comment: What do you mean with "it works". What do you mean with "it breaks". Please describe in detail what you expected to happen and what happened instead when you moved that code outside the `for` loop.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt thanks for your feedback. Added some information. Is it clearer now?

Comment: These are not arrays but slices. Read the blog post on blog.go.dev about slices and how they work.

Comment: @Volker in this particular example it doesn't matter, I neither modify "c" or "r" nor append to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that `I neither modify "c" or "r" nor append to them`, which is partially true.

In the first iteration of the loop,
the slices `c` and `curr` point to different backing arrays, so this is fine.

But when you do

```
curr = c
```

a bit later, you're actually assigning both slices to point to the same backing array.

This means that on the second iteration, your `append` could modify both `c` and `curr` ("could" because a resize would change the backing array for `curr`).

This is what's causing the strange behavior you see above.

Slices in go are a bit tricky, so when you know you'll be mutating and passing them around, it's better to avoid assignments, but rather stick to copying them entirely (as you do in the "WORKS" case).

For further reading this is a nice resource: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro